# Codegeneration with julia

Tags: julia

I want to overwrite the default string-methods ( since I find them ugly ) for my own types.

This function will be used to generate the string

```
function prettyPrint(value::Any)
  names::Vector{Symbol} = fieldnames(value)
  nameCount::Int64 = length(names)
  stringBuilder::IOBuffer = IOBuffer()
  print(stringBuilder, string(typeof(value).name) *"(")
  for (index, name) in enumerate(names)
    print(stringBuilder, string(name) * "=" * string(getfield(value, name)))
    if index != nameCount
      print(stringBuilder, ", ")
    end
  end
  print(stringBuilder, ")")
  takebuf_string(stringBuilder)
end
```

Lets define a sample type

```
type Foo
  a::Int64
  b::String
  c::Float64
end
```

Then I tried to generate the string-function using this bit of code

```
import Base.string

for dataType in (:Foo)
  eval(quote
       function string(dt::$dataType)
        prettyPrint(dt)
       end
       end)
end

foo = Foo(1, "2", 3.0)
println(string(foo))
```

This will crash with a lengthy error message telling me nothing I can work with.

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching start(::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  start(!Matched::SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:170
  start(!Matched::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:258
  start(!Matched::IntSet) at intset.jl:184
  ...
 in anonymous at .\<missing>:?
 in include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:488
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:265
 in _start() at .\client.jl:321
while loading ~\codegeneration.jl, in expression starting on line 24
```

Line 24 being the 'for dataType in (:Foo)'-line.

To be honest I would like this functionality as a macro, but I can't even see how I would do that.

```
macro PrettyPrint(someType)
   ? someType is an expression, how do I get to the type
   ? how do I even know what part of the expression is the type

end
@PrettyPrint type Foo
 a::Int64 ... end
```

Comment: You should really not be doing code generation with strings – use real metaprogramming, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message you are getting is because `(:Foo) == :Foo`. I think you wanted a tuple to iterate over, so you need `(:Foo,)`. That said, `eval` is not the preferred way of doing this.

If you do

```
function Base.show(io::IO, dt::Foo)
    print(io,prettyprint(dt))
end
```

it will change the default printing in the repl, and you can get a string version with `repr`.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to write dozens of those function by hand. Thats why I use code generation.

Comment: @Nozdrum - just use a union: `Base.show(io::IO, dt::Union{Foo, Bar, Baz})`.